# Handling Pointer and Reference Types in C++ Template Specialization

Tags: c++

I'm currently facing a challenge in C++ template metaprogramming involving the handling of pointer (Derived*) and reference (Derived&) types. My template, valid_type, aims to check if a given type is derived from a specified base class. It works correctly for direct class types, but does not yield the expected results for pointers and references.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// General-purpose template constraint checker
template <typename Type, typename Expected>
struct valid_type : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<Type, Expected>::value || std::is_base_of<Expected, Type>::value> {};

class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

class Unrelated {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    // Return true if Derived is derived from Base or is the same as Base
    std::cout << "Derived is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Derived, Base>::value << std::endl;

    // Return false for pointer types
    std::cout << "Derived* is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Derived*, Base>::value << std::endl;

    // Return false for reference types
    std::cout << "Derived& is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Derived&, Base>::value << std::endl;

    // Return false for unrelated types
    std::cout << "Unrelated is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Unrelated, Base>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The issue arises specifically with pointers and references, where the template fails to correctly identify the base-derived relationship. I'm exploring possible solutions and have considered using std::remove_pointer and std::remove_reference, but I'm uncertain if this is the best practice in C++.

I'm seeking suggestions for a more efficient or standard approach to handle this situation. Also, if anyone could provide references to documentation, authoritative guides, or relevant examples, that would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking to deepen my understanding of the best practices in C++ template metaprogramming, particularly in scenarios involving type manipulation with pointers and references.

Thank you in advance for any help and resources you can provide!

Comment: `Derived*` does not inherit from `Base*`. You miss to explain what `valid_type` should actually do and what you expect in case of pointers/references, and why you think `remove_pointer` / `reference` wouldnt be right

Comment: It might also be useful to point out that `Derived*` is not a class type, but a pointer type. Only class types can have base types, and that base type _also_ has to be a class type. Therefor, `Base*` can't be a base type either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compiled your program as written with MSVC, it produced this output:

```
Derived is a valid type of Base: true
Derived* is a valid type of Base: false
Derived& is a valid type of Base: false
Unrelated is a valid type of Base: false
```

Is that what you expected? Or do you want to return `true` for pointers and references?

You can get that by using specializations, but first, some caveats:

- An *lvalue reference to `T`* is not the same type as `T`.
- Similarly, a *pointer to `T`* is not the same type as `T`.

Perhaps obvious, but worth mentioning in case readers mistook the the name of your template, `valid_type`, as somehow implying an equivalance between `T` and *reference to `T`* or *pointer to `T`*.

That said, you can get your program to give the answer `true` using template specializations for the cases of reference and pointer.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// General-purpose template constraint checker
template <typename Type, typename Expected>
struct valid_type : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<Type, Expected>::value || std::is_base_of<Expected, Type>::value> {};

// Specialization for lvalue references
template <typename Type, typename Expected>
struct valid_type<Type&, Expected> : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<Type, Expected>::value || std::is_base_of<Expected, Type>::value> {};

// Specialization for pointers
template <typename Type, typename Expected>
struct valid_type<Type*, Expected> : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<Type, Expected>::value || std::is_base_of<Expected, Type>::value> {};

class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

class Unrelated {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    // Return `true` if Derived is derived from Base or is the same as Base
    std::cout << "Derived is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Derived, Base>::value << std::endl;

    // Return `true` for pointer types
    std::cout << "Derived* is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Derived*, Base>::value << std::endl;

    // Return `true` for reference types
    std::cout << "Derived& is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Derived&, Base>::value << std::endl;

    // Return `false` for unrelated types
    std::cout << "Unrelated is a valid type of Base: " << valid_type<Unrelated, Base>::value << std::endl;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
Derived is a valid type of Base: true
Derived* is a valid type of Base: true
Derived& is a valid type of Base: true
Unrelated is a valid type of Base: false
```